# updated shell script code as suggested: Need to know command for "sed" in replacing values

Tags: linux, shell, sed, workflow, oozie

Am creating a wrapper for moving data from mysql to hdfs using sqoop through Oozie from shellscript.

I have an "InputFile" containing  Source database, tables to be imported and the hdfs output directory from which the 'while-loop' in "Shell_Script.sh" reads it and checks for the sourceDB, if it is 'Mysql' then inside 'if-loop' it assigns the corresponding Mysql parameters to the mentioned variables in ShellScript.sh file.

I have "Sqoop_job.property file" in which I'have mentioned the Database parameters as generic from which the "Oozie workflow" gets the values for execution. In order to perform my Data-Ingestion in a generic way, I haven't mentioned the DB parameters directly in the Sqoop_job.property file.

Hence I should replace it through the "Shell_Script.sh" file. So I've tried to use "sed-command" for replacing the values of DB parameters from InputFile(SourceDB,db_name,Mysql_table,hdfsdir) and also from the assigned variables from the "if-condition"(driver,jdbcUri,UserName, Password)

On execution of "Shell_Script.sh" file my oozie job  throws Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: generic

InputFile.txt: It is a text file containing the DB details along with input and output path.

```
    # SourceDB|db_name|Mysql_table|hdfsdir
    Mysql|sqoop_check|WrapperTbl|/root/SqoopWrapper2/output1
    Mysql|sqoop_check|WrapperTbl2|/root/SqoopWrapper2/output2
```

Sqoop_job.property: " The file that contains hadoop and mysql parameters as generic"

```
oozie.wf.application.path=/root/SqoopWrapper2/sqoop_workflow.xml
SourceDB=generic
db_name=generic
Mysql_table=generic
driver=generic
jdbcUri=generic
UserName=generic
Password=generic
hdfsdir=generic
```

SqoopScript.sh : " It is a script file on reading the input file it checks for DB source and get values from the InputFile & values assigned from 'if-loop'  and creates a new Scoop_job.property file and executes the oozie workflow.xml "

```
# Assigned path of input file and reading it thro' while loop

  input=/root/SqoopWrapper2/InputFile.txt

IFS='|'

while read -r SourceDB db_name Mysql_table hdfsdir 

do
```

# Checks for source DB onreading the InputFile and assigns the corresponding DB parameters.

```
    if [ "$SourceDB" = "Mysql" ]
        then
        driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        jdbcUri=jdbc:mysql://edgenode:3306
        UserName=****
        Password=*****
```

# The values of SourceDB,db_name,Mysql_table,hdfsdir,driver,jdbcUri,UserName, Password should be replaced instead of "generic" in Scoop_job.property file and should create a new Scoop_job.property file in order to execute oozie workflow.xml as it calls the property file.

```
        sed -e 's/SourceDB=generic/SourceDB="$SourceDB"/' > sqoop_job.properties
        sed -e 's/db_name=generic/db_name="$db_name"/' > sqoop_job.properties
        sed -e 's/Mysql_table=generic/Mysql_table="$Mysql_table"/'  > sqoop_job.properties
        sed -e 's/hdfsdir=generic/hdfsdir="$hdfsdir"/'  > sqoop_job.properties

        sed -e 's/jdbcUri=generic/jdbcUri="$jdbcUri"/'  > sqoop_job.properties
        sed -e 's/driver=generic/driver="$driver"/' > sqoop_job.properties
        sed -e 's/UserName=generic/UserName="$Username"/' > sqoop_job.properties
        sed -e 's/Password=generic/Password="$Password"/' > sqoop_job.properties

        fi
```

# Oozie job executes on calling the sqoop_job.property file.

```
ooziejob=$(oozie job -oozie http://oozieserver/oozie -config /root/SqoopWrapper2/prop/sqoop_job.properties -run);

echo $ooziejob;

done < "$input"

exit 0
```

Oozie worflow.xml: "consist of sqoop actions to import data from mysql table to hdfs directory by getting values from Sqoop_job.property file"

```
    <workflow-app name="sqoop-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">

    <global>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </global>
    <start to ="SqoopJob" />
    <action name="SqoopJob">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>

            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>  


    <arg>  import     </arg>
<arg>  --connect  </arg>
<arg>  ${jdbcUri} </arg>
<arg>  --username </arg>
<arg>  ${UserName}</arg>
<arg>  --password </arg>
<arg>  ${Password}</arg>
<arg>  --table    </arg>
<arg>  ${Mysql_table}    </arg>
<arg>  --target-dir </arg>
<arg>  ${hdfsdir}    </arg>
<arg>  --driver     </arg>
<arg>  &{driver}  </arg>
<arg>-m</arg>
<arg>1</arg>

    </sqoop>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="kill"/>
    </action>
   <kill name='kill'>
        <message>Something went wrong</message>

    </kill>

    <end name='end' /> 
 </workflow-app>
```

Comment: `[ SourceDB = Mysql ]` doesn't compare variables - I guess you want `[ "$SourceDB" = "$Mysql" ]`. To use variables inside a sed substitution, you need to use double quotes. There should be no spaces around the `=` in an assignment. Go to http://shellcheck.net and address the issues raised there.

Comment: I've modified my shell script as per the suggestions given and now facing issue that value of "driver,jdbcUri,UserName, Password" is not taken from "if-condition" to sed command replacement in the job.prop f and also the value of SourceDB,db_name,Mysql_table,hdfsdir" from InputFile.txt is not taken.

Comment: There are still things obviously wrong with your code but it's not clear exactly what you're trying to do. It's unclear what you're trying to do with the sed commands but it's almost certainly wrong at the moment. I suggest you break your problem up into smaller parts and ask about specific things, rather than posting your broken code and hoping that we can work out what's going on.

Comment: I've edited and explained clearly @TomFenech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1- You are missing the last `sed` delimiter "|".

For example:

```
sed -e 's|SourceDB=generic|sourceDB=$SourceDB|'
```

2- You have to tell `sed` where you want to apply the command (file or variable), for example:

```
sed -e 's/SourceDB=generic/sourceDB=$SourceDB/' filename.txt
```

or

```
echo $variable | sed -e 's/SourceDB=generic/sourceDB=$SourceDB/'
```

3- With ">" operator, you will be always overwriting your output file. If you want to append new lines you must use ">>". For example:

```
sed -e 's/SourceDB=generic/sourceDB=$SourceDB/' filename.txt >> outputfile.txt
```

Comment: oozie job is being executed after changing it to `sed -e 's/SourceDB=generic/sourceDB=$SourceDB/' > sqoop_job.properties`. But now oozie job is failing with the **error:  org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain.setYarnTag(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V ** . I want to know in sed command which i've mentioned, takes the value of SourceDB from InputFile and replaces it in sqoop_job.prop file.  @Zumo